# How to set backpress Android back button not working in fragment

Tags: java, android

I am new to android,Fragmentbell to fragmenthome back not working [image] how to fix fragmentbell to fragmenthome **private void goToHome() {** not working this line backpress see this image any how to fix this erro not working any backpress

```
   public class Fragmentbell extends Fragment {


    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    private View root_view;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    private Adapterbell adapterbell;
    public static final String EXTRA_OBJC = "key.EXTRA_OBJC";
    DbHandler databaseHandler;

    private ArrayList<bell> mNotificationList;

    private ShimmerFrameLayout lyt_shimmer;
    SharedPref sharedPref;
    private List<bell> data = new ArrayList<>();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState ) {

        root_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bell, container, false);


        //Call this method before you set you adapter
        //then set your adapter
        loadDataFromDatabase();

        recyclerView = root_view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new EqualSpacingItemDecoration(0));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

//set data and list adapter
        adapterbell = new Adapterbell(getActivity(), recyclerView, data);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterbell);

        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));


// on item list clicked
        adapterbell.setOnItemClickListener(( v, obj, position ) -> {


            databaseHandler = new DbHandler(getActivity());

            databaseHandler.updateStatus(data.get(position).getId(), true);


            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).showInterstitialAd();


//            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.valueOf(data.get(position).gettitle()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityNotificationDetail.class);
//
            intent.putExtra("id", (data.get(position).getpost_id()));


            Log.v("testti", "" + v.getTag() + " apakah sama " + data.get(position).getpost_id());


            this.startActivity(intent);


        });






        //initShimmerLayout();

        return root_view;
    }


    private void loadDataFromDatabase() {
        databaseHandler = new DbHandler(getActivity());
        data = databaseHandler.getAllbell();

    }


    
    public void onBackPressed() {
        goToHome();
    }

    private void goToHome() {


        Fragment newFragment = new FragmentHome();
        // consider using Java coding conventions (upper first char class names!!!)
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();

    }

    


}
```

backpress fragmentbell to fragmenthome  not working how to fix this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `onBackPressed()` in your fragment is not called from anywhere. It doesn't work the same as in an activity. In the method on create of your fragment, try something like this:

```
requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            @Override
            public void handleOnBackPressed() {
                goToHome();
            }
        });
```

Here are the docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back#implement

However, if you added to the back stack the transaction to show the `Fragmentbell` then going back should work without having to implement it.

Comment: https://i.postimg.cc/nh64z0Y0/Screenshot-209.png